# THREE.JS + 4K VIDEO TEXTURE + MOBILE = NO

Tags: mobile, three.js, webgl

This is my second post on this subject.

4k video textures, such as 4096 x 2048, do not render on iOS or Android with three.js. The 4k video file's bitrate, frame rate and profile (baseline, main) make no difference. No combination of settings work. 4k video files simply will not render on any mobile device using three.js. Video files below 4k, such as 3000 x 1500 etc, will visually render but performance is significantly affected as the file is not a power of 2.

A significant number of tests have been made to overcome this limitation. Nothing works, however. 4k video textures don't render on either mobile browsers in a Cordova + Crosswalk developed application.

All tests have been made on relatively new devices, such as the iPad Air 2 (iOS 10.2.1) and an Android based Huawei P8 Max. Upon visiting www.webglreport.com on the iPad Air 2, it states the Max Texture Size and Max Cube Map Texture Size are 4096. So, technically three.js should handle the 4k (4096 x 2048) size.

Based on our tests, I believe this is an issue related to three.js. Any time or thoughts put on this would be tremendously appreciated as we've been dealing with this issue for quite a long time now.

Comment: Would definitely like to see an answer to this one way or another. Does three.js support 4k video textures on mobile devices? Specifically, devices that technically support WebGL 4096 x 4096 video textures (as noted by visiting http://webglreport.com/)

If a device technically supports WebGL 4k video textures, is the issue not related to three.js?

Comment: Chrome Android is able to view* the raw 4k video. A 4k video was able to load in Chrome Android v55.0.2883 under Android v5.5. This should further indicate that the issue is related to three.js. *To test a 4k video in Chrome Android, you just add the "file:///sdcard/" url in Chrome and navigate to the 4k video you want to test.

It would be nice to see this issue resolved. If the device supports 4k video textures (www.webglreport.com), then three.js should support them as well.